# Маршрут через несколько точек

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Никак не получается проложить маршрут по заданным динамически точкам
выдает ошибку: can't construct a route

```
$(document).on('click', '.way-go', function () {
    $.getJSON('http://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&geocode=' + 
    $('.way-begin input').val(), function (data) {
        var gobj = data.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember[0];
        var gobj_pos = gobj.GeoObject.Point.pos.split(' ').reverse();
    var waypoints = "";
    $('.way-item').each(function () {
        waypoints = waypoints + ", [" + $(this).data('geoposition') + "]";
    });
    waypoints = waypoints.substr(2);

    waypoints = "[" + gobj_pos + "], " + waypoints;

    console.log(waypoints);// если подставить в route то что выдает консоль -маршрут строится без проблем

    ymaps.route([waypoints]).then(
        function (route) {
            myMap.geoObjects.add(route);
        },
        function (error) {
            alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + error.message);
        }

    );
    });


    });
```

адрес: gastro.promeng.tk/index2

Answer (score 1):

Вы передаете в `ymaps.route` массив со строкой внутри, вместо массива строк. Вам надо собирать в `waypoints` не строку, а массив:

```
var waypoints = $('.way-item').map(function () {
    return $(this).data('geoposition');
}).get();

waypoints.unshift(gobj_pos);

ymaps.route(waypoints).then(...)
```

Comment: да, действительно, вы правы, и   ymaps.route([waypoints]).then( нужно подправить на   ymaps.route(waypoints).then(

Comment: Да, про `route` забыл. Дополнил ответ.